# How to fetch rows with MAX condition involving multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have an `Employee` table with the following columns:

- Emp_Id
- Emp_Name
- ProjectName
- ProjectStartDate
- ProjectEndDate
- Emp_ManagerId

Every employee can work in multiple projects at the same time.

I want the fetch all the records in the table for each employee with max `ProjectStartDate`. If an employee has multiple records with same `ProjectStartDate` then the record with max `ProjectEndDate` should be returned.

All dates in MM/DD/YYYY

[image]

Comment: Employee and Project really need to be **separate** tables / entities. This is a very bad design you have here....

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` in a subquery to rank the records of each employee by descending project start and end date, and then filter on the top record of each employee in the outer query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        e.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Emp_Id ORDER BY ProjectStartDate DESC, ProjectEndDate  DESC) rn
    FROM Employee e
) x
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, as in:

```
select *
from (
  select
    *,
    row_number() over(partition by emp_id 
      order by projectstartdate desc, projectenddate desc) as rn
  from employee
) x
where rn = 1
```